# How to get two divs with the same width with a vertical line between them

Tags: css

In principal I only have to take care of FireFox.

For my content I want to have two div's that have the same width and with a vertical line between them that takes the whole height, with 20 pixels of the top of the bottom.

I got under-way, but the right div is much to small and I also do not know how to get the vertical line.

At the moment I have the following:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang = "nl" lang = "nl">

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color:                      #18A5D7;
      }

      html, body {
        height:                     100%;
        margin:                     0px;
      }

      #container {
        background:                 linear-gradient(blue, white);
        height:                     100%;
        margin:                     auto;
        width:                      100%;
      }

      #footer {
        height:                     auto;
        margin:                     auto;
        position:                   relative;
        width:                      100%;
      }

      #main {
        overflow:                   auto;
      }

      .col {
      }

      .row {
        background-color:           white;
        display:                    flex;
        border:                     1px solid black;
        border-radius:              10px;
        margin-left:                50px;
        margin-right:               50px;
      }

      .title {
        font-weight:                bold;
      }

      button.no {
        background:                 #84a0C4;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius:    10px;
        color:                      #FFFFFF;
      }

      button.yes {
        background:                 #84a0C4;
        border-bottom-left-radius:  10px;
        border-top-left-radius:     10px;
        color:                      #FFFFFF;
      }

      div.block {
        background:                 #E6EBF1;
        border-radius:              15px;
        color:                      #1C589B;
        margin-bottom:              10px;
        padding:                    10px 20px;
      }

      div.content {
        border-style:               solid;
      }

      div.vl {
        border-left:                2px solid grey;
        width:                      0;
        height:                     auto;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      function doResize() {
        var footer_height    = $('#footer').height()
        footer_height       += 2
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', '-' + footer_height + 'px')
        $('#main').css('padding-bottom', footer_height + 'px')
        var footer_position  = $('#footer').offset().top + window.screenY
        var content_position = $('#content').offset().top + window.screenY
        var newHeight        = footer_position - content_position - 2
        var newWidth         = $(document).width() - 100
        $('#content').css({
          'height': newHeight,
          'width':  newWidth
        })
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        doResize()
      })
      $(window).resize(function() {
        doResize()
      })
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="header"><div class="header">
              Header
            </div></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col" id="content">
                <h1>03 Complaints</h1>
                Question one
                <br/><br/>
                Question two
                <br/><br/>
              </div>
<!-- I tried, but it did not work, puts content in the border
              <div class="col vl" >
--->
              <div class="col" >
                Be short, concise and to the point
                <br/>
                Stick to the medical terms
                <br/>
                Questioning
                <br/>
                Stick to the medical terms
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><div class="footer">Footer</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the two divs the same width, you need to add a `css class` that works for both of them, like:

```
div.col {
          width: 50%;
          word-wrap: break-word;
      }
```

And to make the vertical line in between them, you need to make a `div` and put it between the two divs to act as the divider, like:

```
//your div 1
    <div id="divider"></div>
//your div 2
```

and adding some `css` to make it look a vertical line :

```
#divider {
          width: 2px;
          background: gray;
          height: inherit;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
```

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkh3R/3/)**

Comment: They are (with a wide screen) not the same width, but the lines are not broken down any-more. I need to fiddle a little, but it is a big step in the right direction.

Comment: This was why it did not work:

`    var newWidth         = $(document).width() - 100
        $('#content').css({
          'height': newHeight,
          'width':  newWidth
        })
`
I changed it to:
        var newWidth         = $(document).width() / 2 - 50
        $('#content, #comment').css({
          'height': newHeight,
          'width':  newWidth
        })

and problem solved.